# How to terminate the running command of PHP exec() launched?

Tags: php, exec

I am using **windows OS** with **wamp system** installed.

My question is :

How to stop or terminate the **running command** of **PHP exec()** launched? In my situation,I will launch several command at the same time, and is it has something like **IDs** which corresponding,so I can stop the **running command** I want?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the same logic applies when using Windows OS, but you will want to do it in two steps.

1) When you launch the process from php - you'll need to fork, so that your actual PHP doesn't hang. I'm used to doing it in perl, i'm sure php does it too.

2) Whatever program you launch, if you can get its PID then store it in a database. If it's a unique executable name then just run `taskkill /IM uniquename.exe` or `taskkill /PID ####` if you have the PID

Comment: You mean Process Control functions?? The php document note:This extension is not available on Windows platforms.

Comment: Meh... do it in perl then. php calls perl, perl forks the processes, and returns the PID (again, no idea how to do that on Windows)