# Terminating shell_exec() after a few seconds

Tags: php, shell-exec

So I have this code where I execute a c++ program. `$out` simply contains the output of the program.

```
$cmd = "c:/Server/www/Codice/LOGS/".$_SESSION['username']."/chorva.exe";
$out = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $out;
```

And that works. However, I want to terminate the program after a few seconds, say after 6-10 seconds. (This is equivalent to `Ctrl-C`when you are in a terminal.) This is so if the program executes too long (or endlessly e.g. infinite loops), it doesn't have to wait. I am also concerned with the output it produces in that time (if that's even possible). How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Run a program as child using `&` and let it send `kil -9` to `$PPID` after waiting for some time. (sleep 6 for example)

Comment: maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759563/how-to-terminate-the-running-command-of-php-exec-launched

Comment: @KerrekSB username is actually a number soo...

Comment: @Manu343726 Ok. but I didn't say it was. But also, I think it does have something to do with PHP because the code is actually in PHP

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Fixed

Comment: Hi @MohitJain please do elaborate. I honestly don't have any idea about `$PPID` thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows PHP there doesn't seem to be a way of running a program asynchronously AND reading its output AND killing it after a certain period, so I would like to recommend using an external program to do it.

I don't know if any such program already exists, but you can always create your own. And supposing you want to stick to scripting languages, here's an example of such program on VBScript

```
Dim WshShell, objFSO, oExec, cmd, wait, tempFile, objFile
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

wait = WScript.Arguments(0)
cmd = WScript.Arguments(1)
tempFile = objFSO.GetTempName()

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(cmd & " > " & tempFile)

Do While oExec.Status <> 1
     WScript.Sleep 100
     wait = wait - 100
     If wait <= 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

oExec.Terminate()

Const ForReading = 1
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(tempFile, ForReading)
Do While objFile.AtEndOfStream = False
    Wscript.Echo(objFile.ReadLine())
Loop
objFile.Close()
objFSO.DeleteFile(tempFile)
```

The script runs a program `cmd`, waits until it's dead in 100 millisecond ticks, and if it doesn't die in `wait` milliseconds, kills it. The program output is saved into a temporary file, which is read and echoed.
`wait` and `cmd` are first and second script arguments. The script is run as

```
cscript //Nologo runcmd.vbs <time> <cmd>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I will mark this question as solved then!